# Handling ChartJS via Flask

Tags: python, flask

I am making a project that scans a website, saves some information and shows it in a graph.

I am using Flask and ChartJS to display everything.

Basically, I made a class called Snapshot that looks something like this:

```
class Snapshot:
    list_1 = ['id1', 'id2', 'id3']
    list_1_score = [ 10, 15, 20 ]
    timestamp = '19:50'
```

Now, what I want to display in the chart is of course all the snapshots I took of this website.

Unfortunately, ChartJS expects this kind of format:

```
data: {
            labels: ['January', 'February', 'March', 'April', 'May', 'June', 'July'],
            datasets: [{
                label: 'My First dataset',
                backgroundColor: window.chartColors.red,
                borderColor: window.chartColors.red,
                data: [
                    randomScalingFactor(),
                    randomScalingFactor(),
                    randomScalingFactor(),
                    randomScalingFactor(),
                    randomScalingFactor(),
                    randomScalingFactor(),
                    randomScalingFactor()
                ],
                fill: false,
            }, {
                label: 'My Second dataset',
                fill: false,
                backgroundColor: window.chartColors.blue,
                borderColor: window.chartColors.blue,
                data: [
                    randomScalingFactor(),
                    randomScalingFactor(),
                    randomScalingFactor(),
                    randomScalingFactor(),
                    randomScalingFactor(),
                    randomScalingFactor(),
                    randomScalingFactor()
                ],
            }]
        }
```

which is 'incompatible' with mine. Keep in mind that entries in list_1 might disappear too.

The actual template I use is

```
data: {
            labels: {{timestamps|safe}},

            datasets: [
                {% for item in labels %}
                {label: '{{item}}',
                {{ dataset[loop.index0] }}
                {% if loop.length != loop.index1 %}
                    ,
                {% endif %}

                {% endfor %}

            ]
        }
```

I am a bit confused on how I can generate the datasets considering that:

1) IDs might disappear (the content was deleted)

2) IDs might appear (the content was just added)

Of course, if ID's do appear, they should appear starting from the timestamp of the snapshot they appear in (how would I do such a thing?, do I fill the data section with `None` or what?).